# Punteros .next y new node en C++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente algoritmo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class node{
    public:
        int info;
        node *next;
};

node *p, *q;
int *e, i, **f;

int main(){
    p = new node;
    e = new int;

    *e = 0;
    f = &e;

    (*p).next = new node;
    q = &(*p);

    p = (*p).next;

    return 0; }
```

No entiendo que sucede al realizar `(*p).next = new node`, no se si ahora lo apuntado por `p`, ahora apunta a un nuevo nodo. Y cuando hace `p = (*p).next` en realidad le asigna a la variable `new node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las siguientes dos líneas son equivalentes:

```
(*p).next = new node;
p->next = new node;
```

y lo único que hacen es crear un nuevo nodo y apuntar su dirección de memoria en `p->next`. Es decir, esta línea **no modifica `p`**, que sigue apuntando al mismo nodo que antes de ejecutar esta instrucción.

En cambio, esta otra línea:

```
p = (*p).next;
```

Sí que modifica `p`. En este caso hace que `p` apunte al nodo apuntado por `p->next`. Dicho en cristiano, el puntero avanza una posición en la lista.

Antes de ejecutar esa línea:

```
nodo0 -> nodo1 -> nodo2 -> nodo3
^        ^
p        p->next
```

Después de ejecutar esa instrucción:

```
nodo0 -> nodo1 -> nodo2 -> nodo3
         ^        ^
         p        p->next
```

Date cuenta que al avanzar en la lista es irrelevante si el nodo ha sido creado con `new` o no. Lo único importante en este punto es cómo te mueves a lo largo de una lista enlazada.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!